# jQuery toggle delay as well as classes and fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

So I have the following code:

```
$('[data-hook="chat"]').click(function () {
        $('[data-hook="case"]').toggleClass('col-sm-12 col-sm-9');
        $('.chat').delay(500).fadeToggle('slow');
});
```

Which works really well when it is applying the `col-sm-9` class then fading in the chat (Note this is a CSS width transition on the `col-sm-12` element hence the `500ms` delay on the jQuery `fadeToggle()`). My question is can I cleanly reverse this so when fading out and re-applying `col-sm-12` the delay is applied to the `toggleClass()` and the `fadeToggle` is instant?

Cheers,
Otis.

Answer (score 1):

What's preventing you from doing the opposite?

```js
$('[data-hook="case"]').delay(500).toggleClass('col-sm-12 col-sm-9');
$('.chat').fadeToggle('slow');
```

Answer (score 1):

See [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) description and then you can do it like this:

```
$('.chat').fadeToggle('slow', 'swing', function() {
    $('[data-hook="case"]').delay(500).toggleClass('col-sm-12 col-sm-9');
});
```

**UPDATE:**
You can use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/):

```
$('[data-hook="chat"]').toggle(function() {
    $('[data-hook="case"]').toggleClass('col-sm-12 col-sm-9');
    $('.chat').delay(500).fadeToggle('slow');
}, function() {
    $('.chat').fadeToggle('slow', 'swing', function() {
        $('[data-hook="case"]').delay(500).toggleClass('col-sm-12 col-sm-9');
    });
});
```

Comment: If I do this it appears before the `col-sm-9` transition it works one way but now I have the same problem the other way.

Comment: Hey that almost works but it now hides the `$('[data-hook="chat"]')` which is the toggle button :)